# How to add a footer to the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, footer

I'me using this code to add a footer to the TableView. It has 20 sections, and each section a few rows. There's a titleForHeaderInSection, and sectionForSectionIndexTitle methods.

```
CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
tableFooter.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableFooter.backgroundColor = [self.theTable backgroundColor];
tableFooter.opaque = YES;
tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
tableFooter.text = @"test";
self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter;
[tableFooter release];
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks,

RL

Comment: What do you see? Is this code in `viewForFooterInSection:` or some other method?

Comment: @BoltClock nothing appears in the footer. That code is in viewDidLoad, for example.

Comment: @Rui: To make section footers, implement `viewForFooterInSection:`. Make a view, and return that view in the delegate method.

Comment: @BoltClock the footer is for the table, not for the last section of the table.
I implement the method so that I get the footer?
I have the same way in other views, in which the difference is that I have only 1 section.
Thanks, RL

Comment: @BoltClock the footer is for the table. The above code works on another table, but it has only one section. Why?

Comment: That I'm not too sure. What's the style of your table view (plain or grouped)?

Answer (score 37):

I'm specifically seeing in my code that

```
self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter;
```

works and

```
[self.theTable.tableFooterView addSubview:tableFooter];
```

does not work.  So stick to the former and look elsewhere for the possible bug. 
HTH

Comment: addSubview won't work because in this case tableFooterView is nil.

Answer (score 37):

You need to implement the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and return the desired view (e.g. a UILabel with the text you'd like in the footer) for the appropriate section of the table.

Comment: This answer is accurate for creating a footer in each section, but I think the question is about adding a footer for the entire table, regardless of the number of sections.

Comment: @kris still can just count total section and if section  == totalsection.count - 1 then show the footer view.

Answer (score 19):

I used that and it worked Perfectly :)

```
    UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProductCellBackground.png"]]];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:(UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone)];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -500, 0))];
```

Comment: how do i change the footerview at runtime??

Comment: Where specifically did you put this? `viewForFooterInSection` or somewhere else?

Comment: @Adrian, definitely not in `viewForFooterInSection`, that is used for section footers, the above is for the `tableView` not specific to any section. You can put it in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is a pretty old question but I've just met same issue. I don't know exactly why but it seems that tableFooterView can be only an instance of UIView (not "kind of" but "is member")... So in my case I've created new UIView object (for example wrapperView) and add my custom subview to it... In your case, chamge your code from:

```
CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
tableFooter.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableFooter.backgroundColor = [self.theTable backgroundColor];
tableFooter.opaque = YES;
tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
tableFooter.text = @"test";
self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter;
[tableFooter release];
```

to:

```
CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
UIView *wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];

UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
tableFooter.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableFooter.backgroundColor = [self.theTable backgroundColor];
tableFooter.opaque = YES;
tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
tableFooter.text = @"test";

[wrapperView addSubview:tableFooter];

self.theTable.tableFooterView = wrapperView;
[wrapperView release];
[tableFooter release];
```

Hope it helps. It works for me.

Comment: I've got a UIView from a XIB and setting this UIView without the wrapper view doesn't work. It works only when nested in another UIView just like you did. Looks like it's the nesting / some hidden parameter that solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Initially I was just trying the method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but after using this along with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

problem was solved. Sample Program-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sampleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    sampleView.frame = CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 5, 60, 4);
    sampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return sampleView;
}
```

and include UITableViewDelegate protocol.

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: This is adding a footer for each section and not the entire table.

Answer (score 5):

These samples work well. You can check section and then return a height to show or hide section. Don't forget to extend your viewcontroller from `UITableViewDelegate`.

**Objective-C**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        // to hide footer for section 0 
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        // show footer for every section except section 0 
        return HEIGHT_YOU_WANT;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return footerView;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        // to hide footer for section 0
        return 0.0
    } else {
        // show footer for every section except section 0
        return HEIGHT_YOU_WANT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.1.1** below works:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.RGB(53, 60, 62)
        return v
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
```

If use `self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter` there is a space between last row and `tableFooterView`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:footerView];
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter;
```

try

```
[self.theTable.tableFooterView addSubview:tableFooter];
```

Comment: ok. no warning. But the problem exists anyway. The footer of the tableView does not appear...

Comment: The view doesn't appear because -tableFooterView is nil by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I replaced the following line in my header:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewTableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

with this line and it works as expected:

```
@interface RequestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Notice the UIViewController.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't prefer the sticky bottom effect i would put it in `viewDidLoad()` 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38176479/4127670