# How to find the height of the tableView left over by the cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview where some gap is left after the cells are over.
I would like the table's footer to take that space.

How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about exactly what the situation in your table is and what you want to do.   Are you guaranteed that the items in your table always fit on one screen?

Comment: Looks like there's pretty good answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer of a table is automatically displayed after the last of the cells.   If you want to make sure that the footer fills all possible space from the last cell to the bottom of the view then just make the footer the height of the screen.   If you want to dynamically arrange any subviews in your footer so that they are all visible then you probably need to add up the height of all your cells to determine how much of the footer is visible.

Comment: Hey,
There is a problem here. If I give the footer whole height of the screen then even when the table has sufficient cells I can scroll and once i reach bottom, i have that huge gigantic footer that also scrolls up.

Comment: That's why I commented for you to tell more about your table in order to give an accurate solution, I was assuming from what you wrote at first that you had a "short" table that didn't take up one screen.   You can dynamically adjust the frame height of your footer based on how many rows you have or the total height of all your rows.

Comment: What I am doing now is, I have created a method. whenever i need to adjust footer, I call it.
In that method, I am finding the gap between last row and tableview's bottom.
for this method, I am trying to get the last cell in the tableview and finding its bottom's y.
and subtracting it from table's height.
to get the difference which will be footer's new height.

but  [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowCount - 1 inSection: lastSection]]
is returning nil!

Comment: You have basically two cases to handle I think (since you still haven't really given a good description of precisely what you want): 1) the table is 'short' (less than one screen height): then the first approach works, 2) the table is >= 1 screen tall, then you make the footer a fixed height just large enough to fit what you need.

Comment: that table is basically a sidebar on an ipad with list of items.

Comment: Is the list fixed or variable? And how exactly do you want the footer to behave in all circumstances?

Comment: data comes from a web service and is filtered by three buttons at the top and also has a search field to filter it via search in table's headerview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31702/discussion-between-amogh-talpallikar-and-bogatyr)