# How to implement numberOfRowsInSection to add a Button in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with gets populated from a backing array every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. The user can either go Back (via the nav bar) or they must submit the tableview's dataset to a server. Our GUI team wants the interface designed with a 'Done' button as the last cell in the table row in order to submit the dataset. Right now, `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `[myArray count]` and I could conceivably alter the backing array with a "ghost" record for the done button, or simply return `[myArray count] + 1` and catch the mis-matched array count in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Both ways, however, seem like trouble down the road. What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Put the button in the table view footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the button in the [footer for the tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview), or mess with the row count. I've used both methods, just depends how much that last cell needs to look like the rest of the rows (or not look like them, in the case of using the footer)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the footer view a try as suggested by Moxy. If not, I'll just go with fudging the row count.