# How to display UITextfields in UITableviewcell if user hit the "Plus" sign

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i have a `UITableviewCell` and i put the "+" symbol in end of the `UITableviewcell`.My requirement is if i click the "+" sign in `UITableviewcell` three UITextfields displayed in Next `UITableviewcell`.And also i want to display 3 `UITextfields` in first `UITableviewcell` by default.And "+"signs are displayed on total `tableview`.But i want to display "+" signs dynamically. How can i do this functionality.please help me any body.
This is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) 
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:@""];
    UIButton *myGreenIconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [myGreenIconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(GreenIconButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myGreenIconButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"index.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myGreenIconButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myGreenIconButton.frame = CGRectMake(285, 28, 25, 25);
    [cell addSubview:myGreenIconButton];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: 1st Please Format question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the initial no. of sections to one and no. of rows to 3, each row has one `UITextfield` and then after hitting the plus button increment that no. of sections with 1 and reload the `UITableview` using `[tableview reloaddata];`.

Before that you need to add the delegate methods like `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` and `- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` for + button as you need it in the bottom each section.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview) about how to add footer view to each section.

Comment: thanks for your response.But i cant understand.so please tell me detail or give me example based on my code.

Comment: If you want more detail, I need more details, What is myGreenIconButton? what will happen after clicking that button? Where should you need to show the + button? in all rows?

Comment: @thanks for your response. "myGreenIconButton" is the UIButton object name.If i click the "+" button the three UITextfields are displayed in next UITableviewcell. i want to place the + button in end of every uitableviewcell..

Answer (score 0):

Is better use a db or a plist file to setup dynamic table, but
you can insert manually what you want inside the first table in xcode like my screen:

[image: Table with UITextField an UIImage]
Then you can use this with tag:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

UIImageView *logoImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        logoImageView.image = [self.cachedImages valueForKey:identifier];

UILabel *detailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    detailLabel.text = (self.loadImage)[indexPath.row][@"subtitle"];
}
```

Set the tag on interface, select your object and go on attribute inspector:

[image]

When the table load get dynamically your image or text, to pas this information to a `DetailViewController` using

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
}
```

here you can see a `UITableView` plus `plist` tutorial:

[UITableView and Plist tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff3hSLicmaQ)

Hope this help you