# Frame doesn't change properly unless is equal to UIView frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, frame

I have some weird behavior related to frame sizes that I can't fix after hours of trying different things. This just doesn't make any sense.

I have a custom UIView and a related .xib file:

ErrorView.swift

```
import UIKit

class ErrorView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var labelErrorTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    setupView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

func setupView() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ErrorView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(view)
}
```

ErrorView.xib (using inferred size, the label is centered using constraints)

[image: ErrorView.xib]

I want to add this view to a custom UITableView, at the bottom. I want to make it slim, with a height of 45 and a width of the view screen width. I want to add it to the bottom.

Very easy!! I just set the size with a frame like this:

```
class LoadingTableView: UITableView {

var errorView: ErrorView = ErrorView () // Here is the Error View
var errorFrame: CGRect! // The frame (size) I will use

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // I create the frame here to put the error at the top
    errorFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.width,45) 

    // Init the ErrorView 
    errorView = ErrorView(frame: errorFrame)

    // I add the subview to root (I have this rootView created)
    rootView?.addSubview(errorView)

}


// This is needed, it updates the size when layout changes
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // Create the size again
    errorFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.width,45)

    // I update the frame
    errorView.frame = frame
}
```

This should work but it doesn't. The size is just weird. It takes the size from the nib which is 320x568. Then it just moves the frame, but the size doesn't change.

And here comes the great part. If I set the errorView.frame size to .frame, which is the frame of the tableView then it works! With orientation changes and all!

But as long as I change the frame to a custom size, whatever is in awakeFromNib or layoutSubviews it doesn't and starts to act weird.

Why does it keeps the size of the nib? And why if I put .frame it works at it should but a custom size doesn't? It looks like I'm super close, it's frustrating as hell.

The objective is to say tableView.error("errorCode") and then that errorView appears. And it works on all devices and orientations.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout ? If yes, it's not a good practice to alter frames, instead use layout constraints. If no, try to set `translateAutoResizingMak` to `false` of the view that will be added as child. before adding a view as subview.

Comment: Don't `addSubview` to `UITableView`, use [`tableFooterView`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a subview to `UITableView`, use it's `tableFooterView` and `tableHeaderView` properties:

Replace

```
rootView?.addSubview(errorView)
```

With:

```
tableFooterView = errorView
```