# Show amount of cell at the end of the TableView

Tags: dictionary, nsdictionary, plist, uitableview

I have contact list in Table View Controller. how to make sure that at the end of the table show the amount of contacts (or cell)???
I have dictionaries in my plist for cell

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding a footer to the table view and display the number of rows in the footer? Also, in case you don't want you footer to float, try using grouped cell.

Comment: look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using table view footer through below UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Return a label with number of rows in the table. Use `UITableViewStyleGrouped` if you don't want your footer to float.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview) for more details

Comment: {- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section~}
This method is not suitable (or I cant). because I want to create only footer and at the end

Comment: I added this:

`UIView *fview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 105)];
    
    fview.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer.png"]];
   
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = fview; `

Comment: You of course can use the delegate method to create only footer for your table. Also, grouped table would display the header at the end, non-floating, as mentioned in the answer.