# How to place UILabel exactly below UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have UITableView with height of ≤500. Tableview data comes from database. Below UITableView, there is one label and two radio button. The problem is  if data in the UITableView is less than its height, then it shows blank space between UITableView and those two radio button. I want to place those label and radio button exactly below tableview. How should I do this ?

[This is how my tableview looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcm0u.png)

Comment: Does your table view vary in height depending on the data shown?

Answer (score 2):

If the table view's height does indeed vary depending on shown content, you could use `UITableView`'s [`tableFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614976-tablefooterview).

For a bit more context see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144835/1971013) for example.

Alternatively you could do this with basic auto-layout by tying your label and radio buttons (that you place as siblings of the table) vertically to the bottom of the table view.

I could also imagine that you may need a section footer. So you may want to have a look at that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be scrollable, add it as the last row in your table view. You may also go with table view's footer.

If you want it to be sticky at the bottom in case of more rows, go with auto layouts. You may create outlet of table view's height constraint and adjust that accordingly depending on the number of rows. However, this approach is not appreciated.