# Text under table scroll view swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Is there a way to add static text under the bottom of the table view?

The user should swipe up higher than where the scroll ends and if you hold it you can see the text (until you let go).

EDIT: An example of this is on the Snapchat app. In settings, if you continue to scroll higher than the bottom of the scroll view, you see their version number.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question in details along with possible requirement image ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and after looking at snapchat settings, what you want to add is called a footer, please check that question's answers, both in swift and objective-c. : [How to add a footer to the UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview)