# having the powered by google text at the base of a tableView swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi have an application where I use google autocomplete search but I had to write my networking code for it. The issue now is how do I show the Powered by Google text at the base of the tableView? I have check online for resources but havent got any option. Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar things have been asked lots of times previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add image in footer view :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
        if(section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1)
        {
            let footerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.size.width, height:100))
            footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 40, y: 0, width: footerView.frame.size.width - 80, height: 100))
            imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "google_logo")// google logo image
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit        
            footerView.addSubview(imageView)            
            return footerView
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Please note you have to set footerView height as well :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        if(section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1)
        {
            return 100
        }
        else
        {
            return 0.001
        }
    }
```

Comment: @King you can set height according to image.

Comment: I could not get the image to be scaled down

Comment: @King just minimise the height `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit` will work in this case

Comment: still does not scale. The image is too big

Comment: @King can you share screenshot of the output..? so that i can get idea what problem you are facing

Comment: I fix it by changing the `UIViewContentMode.center`