# How to add UITextView to bottom of UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a project where I have to show a lot of information on one screen. It is not too much information, but it is complicated to achieve. For the purpose of this question I suggest to look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfKB5.jpg) that will illustrate what I want to achieve.

I currently set up this screen with a `UIViewController` containing a `UITableView` that is pinned to the top, bottom, leading and trailing anchor of the view using AutoLayout for the middle section. This works great. I then added a `tableHeaderView` which contains the information about the user on top. Now I have just added a second `UITableView` in the `tableFooterView`, and surprisingly, this works like a charm too. I had a bit of trouble with the height, but I managed to get it done in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method. But that's bit off topic.

I am now at the final stage where I want to add a `UITextView` together with a `UIButton` (in a `UIView` container) to allow users to add comments. At first, I added this in the `tableFooterView` and it worked, but as soon as the content was too short (e.g. only one row in the middle and no comments yet), the `UITextView` would appear in the middle of the screen (directly under the contents of the `UITableView`). I read up on this and figured it is the expected behavior of the `tableFooterView`, so I am now trying to figure out a way on how to add this custom view to add comments that will **always** be on the bottom if the content is not filling the entire screen, but will also scroll with the contents if the content is larger than the screen size. (Ideally, I would want to be able to grow or shrink the `UITextView` when a user enters text - might be relevant in case someone suggests contentInsets).

Any suggestions? Should I add a subview directly to the `UITableView` (which is, as far as I read, not recommended)? Should I work with contentInsets on the UITableView and add the `UIView` container as a subview of my main `UIViewController`? I'm a bit lost after searching multiple solutions without finding the right one, so I hope you guys can help me out. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a footer to the UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144835/how-to-add-a-footer-to-the-uitableview)

Comment: How is that a duplicate? They suggest there to use tableFooterView or section footers. tableFooterView is what I currently use for the comments, but then it ends up not being on the bottom when there is too little content. Section footers are out of the question as I want it to be on the bottom of the entire UITableView.

Comment: Possible duplicate could be and could not be.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `UITextView` is tricky because it's subclass of `UIScrollView`, just like `UITableView`, and adding a scroll view to another scroll view is not only difficult for the gesture recognisers to handle, but also for auto-layout.

What would make your life easier is to have just 1 table view in your view controller with different sections, and each section has a different type of cell.

What I like to do for this is declare an `enum` in my view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private enum Section: Int, CaseIterable {
        case foo
        case bar
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Section.allCases.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let section = Section(rawValue: section) else { preconditionFailure() }

        switch section {
        case .foo:
            return 1
        case .bar:
            return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { preconditionFailure() }

        let cell: UITableViewCell
        switch section {
        case .foo:
            cell = ...
        case .bar:
            cell = ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

For the cells with long text you can just use a `default` cell style (in your XIB/storyboard) and set

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

The table view should be able to automatically size itself to fit the entire text.

The only reason you should need to use a `UITextView` in your scenario is if you want the user to be able to edit the text. Otherwise save yourself a lot of pain and go with a `UILabel`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, the entire idea behind what I want to achieve is that users can add a comment, so they would definitely need to be able to edit the text. Take a look at the screenshot I added in my OP, I am trying to add the very bottom "Add Comment..." view.

Answer (score -1):

You should add separate UIView at the bottom of main screen and add UITextView as a subview in it.
Add TableView above this container view so that it scrolls and textview is always visible at the bottom.